# Is there a way to trigger a Hot Key/Keyboard Shortcut via a Shell Script, a AppleScript or a Automator Workflow?

Tags: bash, applescript, shortcut, hotkeys, automator

I'm an avid Keyboard Maestro user and I need a workaround for triggering a keyboard shortcut like ⌘⇧L (externally, without Keyboard Maestro). So I thought a bash script would be capable of doing such a thing. An AppleScript or an Automator workflow would be sufficient, too. I anybody could help me this would be great.

---

You don't have to read this, but here's why I want to do what I want to do:

I have a the same string assigned to various Markdown macros, I use a string instead of Hotkeys because it's much more memorable for me since my brain already is filled with so many application shortcuts. The disadvantage is that Keyboard Maestro won't delete the keystrokes of the string. I can perform several actions within the program to delete them but adding these actions for each and every macro is tedious and suboptimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using command down & shift down
```

Comment: That's great! It is very easy to use and I'm capable without any in-depth knowledge to produce exactly the behavior I want. Thanks so much, this is a lifer saver for me. Now I can go nuts with all kinds of macros and triggers.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code {123, 124} using {shift down, command down} -- ⇧⌘←, ⇧⌘→
    keystroke "c" using command down -- keystroke "C" would be treated as ⇧C
end tell
delay 0.02 -- you need a small delay here before the next command
set txt to Unicode text of (the clipboard as record)
```

Reference of Mac key codes: [lri.me/chars](http://lri.me/chars)

Comment: Hi Lri, thank you for taking the time to write this answer. I was able to produce a variety of Shortcuts with the help of your script and [Key Codes](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) from the Mac App Store.

Sadly the script didn't work with Keyboard Maestro since the Macro opened via the triggered shortcut closed immediately. There must be some kind of 'enter' function.

Anyway, this script is also super useful since I can assign to different key strokes and to modify text this is also superb. It's like tweaking the Key Bindings of the System. Thanks!